# Oracle Forms Builder running forms only over a server

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I had taken over an old Oracle-based system at work. Originally, the previous developer built the forms and reports using Oracle Forms and Reports 6. I somehow managed to install that suite on my Windows 10 PC. I remember I was able to easily 'run' the form for debugging/testing purposes directly.

My PC crashed recently and I took a big loss on data including the working setup for Oracle 6. I have now installed the latest Oracle® Fusion Middleware 12c (12.2.1.3.0). After running into many issues, I finally managed to make it install, configure, and run properly. I can open the old forms easily now:

[image: Form Builder]

But there is an issue: I can no longer run the form for testing. It is trying to connect to a server instead and I get this error:

[image: Error]

I found this URL in the preference dialog and I'm not sure why it is trying to run windows form on a server. Can the v12 not test forms like v6 used to?

[image: Settings]

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forms 6i was client-server (although you could have deployed it on web). Later versions (beginning with 9i, which follows 6i) are web-based only.

I don't use 12c version, but I *think* that you need to install WebLogic server in order to run those forms.

If you could "downgrade" to, say, 10g version, you'd run OC4J instance which allows you to run forms locally, without any kind of a *server* (it was the IAS, Internet Application Server in 10g).

Or, if possible, acquire the 6i Developer Suite installation CD. Note that - as it is a quite old piece of software - you might have problems running it in Windows 10 (it was never supported nor certified combination of Oracle software and operating system). In such a case, I'd install a virtual machine, put Windows XP onto it and install Forms 6i & enjoy.

Comment: Being a pure .Net full-stack developer, your quick response provided me enough insights to get a head start. I'm installing the infrastructure (WebLogic) component right now. I also noticed that the Form setup was not proper as many shortcuts were never created if I compare my experience with the numerous installation tutorials on YouTibe. So I'm re-doing one more time. If I fail, I'll seek out 6i.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should install a Weblogic Server. It's started running file `startWebLogic.cmd` installed in such 
`C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\bin` a default path for `windows` systems.

When this file is started to run, it prompts you for `username`(default `weblogic` unless any other defined ), and password( default `Welcome1` unless any other defined ).

It's suggested to store these info in namely `boot.properties` file in path `C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\servers\AdminServer\security`    by defining credentials in a text file like in the picture below :

[image]

> providing `startWebLogic.cmd` not to prompt user for `username` &
>   `password`

After you complete to run `startWebLogic.cmd` successfully, the file `boot.properties` is encrypted like the following :

[image]

Coming back to our original issue,

When you run your form by pressing `Ctrl+R`, you get `FRM-10142` because of the following two cases :

1. The Weblogic Server is not running
2. The Weblogic Server is running but your port number is not truly
   defined in Runtime Preferences of Forms. It's mostly defined `7001` as default, in your case it's `9001`. The current setting of port number can be seen from last lines of `startWebLogic.cmd` command's screen
   ( where you see string `RUNNING` provided you're successfull to run ) :

> ```
>        <Mar 2, 2018 1:11:45 AM VET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> 
>        <Channel "Default" is now listening on 192.168.27.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
>        <Mar 2, 2018 1:11:45 AM VET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000329>
>        <Started WebLogic Admin Server "AdminServer" for domain "ClassicDomain" running in Production Mode>
>        <Mar 2, 2018 1:11:45 AM VET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365>  
>        <Server state changed to RUNNING>
>        <Mar 2, 2018 1:11:45 AM VET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360>  
>        <Server started in RUNNING mode>
> ```

Notice to the literals `7001` and `RUNNING` in the above text.

Comment: So, the installation of Oracle XE or 12 databases is not required? I have a separate Oracle database server on the network that has all the databases. I was following youtube videos and everyone starts off by installing database first and I cant make that work: The database is working but the listener doesn't work.

Comment: @DoomerDGR8 yes, of course the db is needed, as preliminary assumed to be installed. Did you issue `C:\Program Files\Oracle>lsnrctl sta[tus]rt`, first `status` and then `start` if needed?

Comment: @DoomerDGR8 did you try `C:\Program Files\Oracle>tnsping <your_db_alias>` to resolve the alias of your db?

Comment: What would be the database alias in case of Oracle 11 XE?

Comment: @DoomerDGR8 i don't remember the default alias, and maybe changed during the installation. It's important to get the informations about `sqlnet.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` decently, when you use `tnsping`.

Comment: XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.128.68.152)(PORT = 1521)(IP=V4_ONLY))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

Comment: ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )

Comment: There are three defined in the `D:\Oracle\Database\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166143/discussion-between-barbaros-ozhan-and-doomerdgr8).